Finding $\sum^{100}_{n=1}f\left(\frac{n}{101}\right)$, where $f(a^2-b^2)=(a-b)(f(a)+f(b))$ for real $a$ and $b$, and $f(1)=1/101$

If $$f(a^2-b^2)=(a-b)(f(a)+f(b))$$ for $a,b \in R$, and
$$f(1)=\frac{1}{101}$$ then find the value of
$$\sum^{100}_{n=1}f\left(\frac{n}{101}\right)$$

My observation is that $f(x)=kx$ for $k\in R$ satisfies the functional equation. But I cannot prove it. Best i can do is to show
$$f(1+2n)=f(n)+f(n+1)$$
by putting $b=n$ and $a-b=1$ hence the function at an odd integer as a linear combination of the function at even integers. But this leads nowhere. Please help.

This is quite a common functional equation exercise, so I'd encourage you to play around with it by testing several values and writing down those results. It is indeed true that the only solutions are the linear functions, so try to see how we can make sure that $f(x) / x$ is a constant. Hint: Apart from $(a, b)$, what other pair produces the same value for $a^2 - b^2$?

As written you're saying that you cannot prove that $f(x)=kx$ satisfies the functional equation, which is very easy. You should say something like "but I cannot prove that $f$ is necessarily of that form".

@CalvinLin Got it! We have to prove that $f(-a)=-f(a)$ then put $b=-b$ in the functional equation to get the answer. Thanks!!

Replace $a=b$ in $f(a^2-b^2)=(a-b)(f(a)+f(b))$ then we get
$$f(a^2-a^2)=(a-a)(f(a)+f(b))$$
$$f(0)=0$$
Now replace $b=0$ in $f(a^2-b^2)=(a-b)(f(a)+f(b))$ then we get
$$f(a^2-0)=(a-0)(f(a)+f(0))$$
$$f(a^2)=af(a)$$
Since $f(x)$ behaves in a manner consistent with a linear function we can say that
$$f(x)=kx$$
Now given that $f(1)= \frac{1}{101}$ we can solve for $k$
$$f(1)=k\times 1=\frac{1}{101}$$
$$k=\frac{1}{101}$$
Therefore
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{101}x$$
Now we need to find
$$ \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{100} f(\frac{n}{101}) $$
By Triangular numbers we get
$$\frac{1}{10201}+\frac{2}{10201}+\frac{3}{10201}+...+\frac{100}{10201}=\frac{5050}{10201}$$
Hope it Helps!
